# what does the number 1e18 in ruby mean

Tags: ruby, numbers

I am trying to replace the number 18 in 1e18 with a variable but everything I have tried gives an error. Perhaps if I knew what it does I can be able to write the formula myself differently.

What does the letter 3 do to a number. How can I apply it to a variable called, say, X?

How different is e from **

Comment: The question is too vague and not understandable, can you provide an example?

Comment: It’s scientific notation and means 1*10^18

Comment: _"What does the letter 3 do to a number"_ – what do you mean by that? What _"letter 3"_ are you referring to? Is that a typo and you mean _"the letter **e**"_?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> what does the number 1e18 in ruby mean?

`1e18` (or `1E18`) is a [number literal](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Numbers) using [E-notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E-notation). Ruby interprets this number as a floating point number with the value 1 × 10<sup>18</sup> (i.e. 1,000,000,000,000,000,000).

> I am trying to replace the number 18 in 1e18 with a variable

`1e18` is equivalent to:

```
1.0 * 10 ** 18
#=> 1.0e+18
```

so you can write:

```
x = 18

1.0 * 10 ** x
#=> 1.0e+18
```

or simply:

```
10.0 ** x
#=> 1.0e+18
```

> How different is `e` from `**`

The result is the same, but `1e18` – being a literal – is evaluated by the parser whereas `**` is a method call.

Answer (score 1):

As Sami's comment mentions:

> `1e18` is a scientific notation meaning `1 * 10^18`

[Read more about the number here](http://www.numbers-to-words.com/number/1e18)

**How to work with such numbers in Ruby?**

Here's a simple example:

```
require 'bigdecimal'
a = BigDecimal.new "1e18"
#=> #<BigDecimal:2cf0880,'0.1E19',9(18)>

a.to_f
#=> 1.0e+18

a.to_s
#=> "0.1E19"  # notice 0.1E19 and not 1.0E19

"%f" % a
#=> "1000000000000000000.000000"

("%f" % a).to_i
#=> 1000000000000000000
```